# Display all days in hAxis

Tags: google-visualization

I made a LineChart with Google Charts.

I need to add all days in current months in hAxis.

Actually, I have only display each 3 days (1 september, 4 september, etc ...).

How can I do to have all days ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to share what your data looks like?

Comment: Yes, I can display my data. But I get my data from an API so I can many things. Actually it's just a array with first element date and second number. Size of array is 30.

Comment: please share the options used to draw the chart, a sample of the data would be helpful...